# Maven properties set by plugins are 'too late' for the reactor build plan

Tags: git, maven

I'm in the process of migrating some Maven projects from Perforce to git. With Perforce, these projects were configured with a `build.number` Maven property, that was passed in as a JVM arg as part of the build process. With git, I'm exploring the [jgit-buildnumber plugin](https://github.com/alx3apps/jgit-buildnumber) that sets properties based on git repo metadata.

The plugin works wonderfully, but even if I run it early in the Maven lifecycle (validate or initialize), this happens after the Reactor build plan is generated. This is a problem because the projects use `exec-maven-plugin` and `maven-antrun-plugin`. The build plans for these plugins seem to take a snapshot of all Maven properties at time of plan construction, e.g. a snippet from the Reactor build plan's debug output for one of these plugins:

```
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (RPMbuilderScript)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <basedir default-value="${basedir}"/>
  <classpathScope default-value="runtime">${exec.classpathScope}</classpathScope>
  <commandlineArgs>product=jas_etl
                        dir=/Users/dev/project
                        team=sanctuary
                        version=${git.buildnumber}
                        artifact=/Users/dev/project/target/project-${git.buildnumber}.zip
                        </commandlineArgs>
  <executable>../parent/devops_scripts/mavenRpmBuilder.sh</executable>
  <longClasspath default-value="false">${exec.longClasspath}</longClasspath>
  <outputFile>${exec.outputFile}</outputFile>
  <project default-value="${project}"/>
  <session default-value="${session}"/>
  <skip default-value="false">true</skip>
  <sourceRoot>${sourceRoot}</sourceRoot>
  <testSourceRoot>${testSourceRoot}</testSourceRoot>
  <workingDirectory>${exec.workingdir}</workingDirectory>
</configuration>
```

`git.buildnumber` is set as part of the initialize phase by the jgit-buildnumber plugin, but it's done too late to affect the reference in the exec plugin's build plan.

Is there a way to run the jgit-buildnumber plugin ahead of the generation of the build plan? Alternatively, is there a way to configure the Ant and exec plugins to read property values only at the start of the phase they execute in, rather than at time of build plan generation?